# jQuery sticky navigation bar, deleting content

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I have created a jQuery sticky navigation bar and it works fine but i am trying to improve it without any success.

here is the code:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
        jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");

        if (scrollPos == navOffset) {
        jQuery(".nav_liste").prepend("<li><a>Menu</a></li><li>/</li>");
        jQuery(".nav_liste").append("<li>/</li><li><a>your cart <img src=\"cart.png\"/> (0)</a></li>"); }

        var boo = true;

    } else if (boo === false) {

        return;
    }

    else

    {
        jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
        /*jQuery(".nav_liste:nth-child(1)").remove();
        jQuery(".nav_liste:nth-child(7)").remove();*/
    }

});
```

So while i have succeeded making it sticky and adding two items, i can't find a way of deleting them again (my attempt in the comment). The second problem is that when i add the elements i have to scroll really slowly otherwise it will just skip the adding part.

I hope you can help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are a few issues, firsly `scrollPos == navOffset` only happens if you hit that number **exactly**, which is hard to do unless you scroll really slowly, otherwise the scroll event probably fires every 100px or something similar, meaning you miss your target. As for the removing, are you sure the `nth-child` selector matches, you'd have to have more elements than the ones you create in the posted code ?

Comment: Is there an option to fix the problem with the scrollpos? and yes i have 5 elements in .nav_liste so with the added two that makes seven.